# findOneAndUpdate with $inc not returning anything when findOne returns it

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So when I do this it returns undefined

```
User.findOne({
    phone: phoneTo
}, function (err, user) {
    Payments.findOneAndUpdate({
        companyId : user.company
    },{$inc: {"balance": -2}},function (err, account) {
        console.log(account); // returns undefined
    });
});
```

But when I do this, I get my account in console

```
User.findOne({
    phone: phoneTo
}, function (err, user) {
    Payments.findOne({
        companyId : user.company
    },function (err, account) {
        console.log(account);
    });
});
```

This is what it returns. Here's the Payments model with the balance object.

```
{ _id: 54c182718e911148d9f70c62,
  customerId: 'cus_5Z262sTHkMgu02',
  companyId: '54c182708e911148d9f70c61',
  userId: '54c182708e911148d9f70c60',
  balance: '600',
  __v: 0 }
```

Comment: Balance is a string and not a number.

Comment: I can do account.balance = account.balance -2 and it works fine.

Comment: Check the err in the callback. You know it to be true.

Comment: Thanks, Neil! Appreciate your support.

Comment: List of valid [Schema Types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) and there are other type plugins available. Number should do. While your at it there are several ObjectId values there that also look to be defined as strings

Comment: Neil, my account was banned. Could you please return the votes on this question back to 0?